# Implementing a sine using a bezier curve

Tags: cocos2d-x, curves, beziers

I'm developing a 2D game using Cocos2d-x.
Is possible to use `CCBezierTo` to parameterize a sine function?

Comment: I guess you're talking about a *sine* function? What do you mean when you say *use a bezier curve to parametrize a sine function*? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Make a semi-period, concave or convex. My idea is create a sine, with use function sin, just using curves chained.

Comment: So in the end you want a bezier curve, that matches a sine curve? So that you can use it with `CCBezierTo`. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, it is right. I must not be exactly a sine, because i'm interesting in create a method to make trajectories beautiful. My random experiments with bezier are horrible. Learning to make a sine, it would help me to create more things.

Comment: Theoretically, writing a the `sin` function in terms of polynomials (especially finite series) is mathematically impossible since the basis (be it Bernstein polynomials or your _1_,_x,_,_x^2_,etc.. canonical one) is finite and cannot reproduce the taylor series of the sine function. You may find it faster to just use a truncated Taylor expansion of the sine. But if you aim to "draw" something, you can for sure mimic the images of some simple non-linear functions. (I wrote this comment just for the mathematical caveat.. no trolling intended :D).

Comment: Bezier curves aren't difficult once you've seen these animations. http://www.jasondavies.com/animated-bezier/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use Bezier, giving 3 points in concave section, and another 3 in convex section, its easier than give all points to  do a perfect sine, and the trajectory is the same.

Answer (score 3):

You could create a Bézier curve that matches a sine ([read this article for an example](http://blogs.vertigo.com/personal/Chris/Blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=16)). Creating a Bézier curve from a sine, just to feed into `CCBezierTo` seems like a very counter-intuitive way of doing things though.

I would skip `CCBezierTo` entirely and update the position of your sprite yourself. You could do so in your update method or implement a `CCAction` yourself. The easiest form of movement would be to increase `x` constantly (or with a decaying value to simulate some sort of drag) and use the sine function to calculate `y`.